How to access maps.apple.com on MacOS
Before sending https://maps.apple.com/lat,long to someone who may not have a Mac, I tried to view it myself.
But Safari, DuckDuckGo, and Firefox all asked me if I wnted to open Maps.app
When I declined, it refreshed the previous page.
Is there a way around this short of traveling to a place that has Windows?

You can configure Safari to impersonate Edge for Windows to prevent the redirection to Maps:

Launch Safari.
Select Safari > Settings… to open the Safari Settings window.
In the Advanced pane, enable "Show features for web developers":

Select File > New Private Window to open a new window.
Select Develop > User Agent > Microsoft Edge - Windows and paste the URL in the address bar.


Note that the setting the user agent applies to the current tab of the selected window only.

Don't have time to try it now, but I assume it will work.
